# Deploying Java application to a Linux computer

Tags: java, dll, deployment, jar, .so

I have developed a desktop Java application on Windows using Eclipse. It is just a console application. It uses several third party jar files and on Windows, several third party dll files are also required.

On the Windows machine, I can run the app from a command prompt as well, which I have copied from Eclipse. The command prompt references several of the third party jar files in the -classpath argument.  In the development environment on Windows, all the dll files have been placed in the project home directory. The third party jar files have been included in the project Properties, "Java Build Path" setting on Eclipse.

Now, I want to move and run this app to a Linux computer for deployment.  How should I do it?  One way would be to use the same command line that is being used on the windows machine with modified -classpath arguments with the destination of third party jar files on the Linux machine.  Is that the right approach?  On the linux machine, I would also need the third party Linux native .so files. Should I just copy them to the project directory on the Linux machine?  Should the project directory structure be same as the one I have on my Windows development machine?

Or should I just export (Eclipse Export) everything into a jar file and run the app using java -jar myapp command?  Where should I place the third party jar files and native .so files in that case?

I have read a lot on this topic but still cant get any clarity on whats the best approach especially with third party .dll, .so and jar files involved.

Comment: What are the several third party dll files? Does they have *NIX version?

Comment: I am not familiar with NIX version. But using the dll files is not the issue. Packing the dependent .so files is the issue. Because development is on Windows but runtime environment is Linux. I have made a runnable jar and the jar executes on Linux. But it is looking for .so file and giving error: "Unable to load library 'ABC': Native library (linux-aarch64/ABCCore.so) not found in resource path (MyApp.jar)

Comment: I moved all the .so files to the same directory from where I am running the jar file. This works, all .so files are being used.  But now I have .so files in the jar and in the jar directory as well. Ideally, I just want them to be in the jar file and not have to copy them to the directory separately.